# Tidyr - Separate rows of unequal length - Remove extra strings

Tags: r, string, tidyr

I am using `tidyr::separate_rows` to split my data into rows but I have strings of unequal lengths.  See below example data:

```
`  Df <- data.frame(Id <- c(1, 2, 3),  suburb <- (‘orange, yellow’, ‘blue’, ‘green, yellow’),  postcodes <- (’a9,  b9’, ‘c9, a9’, b9', ‘d9, b9, a9’))`
```

Is there a way I could drop strings in the postcode column if they exceed the string length of the suburb column? For example, if I have one `suburb` and 3 `postcodes`, Is it possible to delete the other 2 superfluous postcodes? I have searched through other answers but can't find anything quite like this.

Comment: Your sample data appears to be manually typed (and wrong, not valid R syntax), and I recommend against using `<-` _inside_ of `data.frame`, just use `=` (they are not the same as function arguments).

Comment: You appear to have pairings with (say) 2 `suburb`s ans 3 `postcodes`. This could be because you hand-typed the data in here, or it could be at the root of your problem. If it is allowed to be mismatched like that, how do you propose the expansion be done, is it a cartesian (outer) join of them?

Answer (score 0):

I *think* your data is really

```r
Df <- structure(list(Id = c(1, 2, 3), suburb = c("orange, yellow", "blue", "green, yellow"), postcodes = c("a9,  b9", "c9, a9", "d9, b9, a9")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -3L))
Df
#   Id         suburb  postcodes
# 1  1 orange, yellow    a9,  b9
# 2  2           blue     c9, a9
# 3  3  green, yellow d9, b9, a9
str(Df)
# 'data.frame': 3 obs. of  3 variables:
#  $ Id       : num  1 2 3
#  $ suburb   : chr  "orange, yellow" "blue" "green, yellow"
#  $ postcodes: chr  "a9,  b9" "c9, a9" "d9, b9, a9"
```

If that's the case, and if you intend an expansion where you have unbalanced `suburb` <--> `postcodes`, then

```r
Df %>%
  mutate(
    across(c(suburb, postcodes), ~ lapply(strsplit(., "[,\\s]+"), trimws)),
    stuff = Map(crossing, suburb=suburb, postcodes=postcodes)
  ) %>%
  select(Id, stuff) %>%
  unnest(stuff)
# # A tibble: 12 x 3
#       Id suburb postcodes
#    <dbl> <chr>  <chr>    
#  1     1 orange a9       
#  2     1 orange b9       
#  3     1 yellow a9       
#  4     1 yellow b9       
#  5     2 blue   a9       
#  6     2 blue   c9       
#  7     3 green  a9       
#  8     3 green  b9       
#  9     3 green  d9       
# 10     3 yellow a9       
# 11     3 yellow b9       
# 12     3 yellow d9
```